# How to count checked checkbox with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to count the checkboxes that are checked and display the count in the Div.

Here is my HTML :

```
<form name="liste_figurine" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" class="z" name="chck1[]" onclick="updateCount()" />
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" class="z" name="chck2[]" onclick="updateCount()" />

</form>

<div id="y"></div>
```

Here is my JS :

```
function updateCount {
    var x = $(".z:checked").length;
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = x;
};
```

Here is an exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/r3todbs6/3/

Sorry, I'm not really used to JS... What is wrong with my code ?

---

Finally, it's working but I have one last issue : the `onclick` must contain 2 functions and I don't manage to make them working together.

Now this function works, alone : `onclick="updateCount()"`

This other function works also, alone : `onclick="document.getElementById(\'radio-'.$ligne['id'].'-2\‌​').c‌​hecked = false"`

But these two functions doesn't work, together : 
`onclick="updateCount(); fx2(document.getElementById(\'radio-'.$ligne['id'].'-1\').ch‌​ecked = false);"`

What is wrong with the third proposition ? Is it a syntax error ?

Comment: `.size()` should be `.length`

Comment: `.length` is not `.length()`

Comment: You may  use `.forEach(value => {  })` to check value of checkbox and count it s amount under condition

Comment: OK, I corrected this. By the way, do I have the obligation to use jquery, as I see you edited my post ?

Comment: @JakubChlebowicz : where should I put this ?

Comment: @A.Lau : corrected

Comment: The pure JavaScript way is `document.querySelectorAll(".z:checked").length`

Comment: `var x = $("").forEach( element => { element.checked ? count++ : null });`

Comment: Oh. My way of doin it is worse, follow @4castle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.updateCount = function() {
    var x = $(".z:checked").length;
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = x;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73yfczcj/

try this. you have to use jquery in javascript setting.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to put this in my original code but I have already something in the `onclick` event. How can I have two functions in it ?

Comment: onclick="fxn1(); fxn2();"

Comment: @Guillaume you can call two functions in onclick event. onclick="updateCount(); someFunction();"

Comment: @kangsu : I have this already (in an echo) : `onclick="document.getElementById(\'radio-'.$ligne['id'].'-2\').checked = false"`. So I tried this but it doesn't work : `onclick="updateCount(); fxn2(document.getElementById(\'radio-'.$ligne['id'].'-2\').checked = false);"`

Answer (score 0):

**Use length**

```
function updateCount(){
    var x = $("input:checked").length;
    $("#y").html(x);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there something more to do ? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues for your Fiddle code:

- As others have mentioned, it should be `length`, not `size()`.
- **You should change the JavaScript setting -> Load type to "No wrap - in `<head>`". Otherwise, `updateCount` is not defined in global scope.**
- You need to configure Fiddle to use jQuery if you use your original code.

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/c5ez4w7y/

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateCount {
    var x = document.querySelector('.z:checked').length;
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = x;
};
```

try this fuction if you don't want to use jQuery

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to put this in my original code but I have already something in the `onclick` event. How can I have two functions in it ?

Comment: onclick="fxn1(); fxn2();"

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by kangsu is the best answer but here is how I did it.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var checkBoxes = $(form).children('.checkbox');
var count = 0;

var divBoxesChecked = document.getElementById('boxesChecked');
divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = 0;

$(checkBoxes).on('click', function() {
  $.each(checkBoxes, function(i) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = count;
  count = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post">

  <input type="checkbox" id="box_01" class="checkbox" name="box_01" />
  <label>Box 1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="box_02" class="checkbox" name="box_02" />
  <label>Box 2</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="box_03" class="checkbox" name="box_03" />
  <label>Box 3</label>

</form>

<div id="boxesChecked"></div>
```

Basically, every time one of the boxes is clicked it counts how many boxes are checked in total and prints that out to the div and the console, then it resets the counter to zero since it re-counts all of the checked boxes every time you click on one.